# What is the simplest form of $ \sum_{r=1}^n (r-1)^2 $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I knew that

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$

So get $\sum_{r=1}^n (r-1)^2$ , will i replace $n$ by $(n-1)$ or anything else ?

Comment: You know that $1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 + n^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$, and you want to know what $0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + \cdots + (n-2)^2 + (n-1)^2$ is. Is that correct?

Comment: replace $r-1$ by $r$, and change the summation index

Comment: Yes Arthur, that's my question in other words

Comment: Then what's stopping you from moving the $n^2$ term over to the right hand side of that first equation?

Comment: while adjusting look at the first and last terms: $\sum_{r=1}^n (r-1)^2=\sum_{r=1}^{n-1} r^2=...$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To counter the ineffectiveness of the other answer, here is the approach I've hinted at in my comments:
$$\begin{align}
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 + n^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\\
1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - n^2\\
0^2 + 1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + \cdots + (n-1)^2 &= \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - n^2
\end{align}
$$
Now it's just a matter of simple algebra to check whether $$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - n^2$$ is actually equal to $$\frac{(n-1)((n-1)+1)(2(n-1)+1)}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

$$s= \sum_{r=1}^n (r-1)^2$$$$\sum_{r=1}^n (r-1)(r-1)$$$$\sum_{r=1}^n (r^2-2r+1)$$$$\sum_{r=1}^nr^2-2\sum_{r=1}^nr+\sum_{r=1}^n1$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)\right)-2\frac{n}{2}(n+1)+n$$
$$\left(\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)\right)-(n^2+n)+n$$
$$s= \frac{n(2n-1)(n-1)}{6}$$